# How can I calculate the derivative of $g(z)=\int_{z^2}^{z^3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}} dt$?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

How can I calculate the derivative of $$g(z)=\int_{z^2}^{z^3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}} dt$$

Is there anything I can do apart from calculating the integral and then derivate?

Comment: Is it $x$ instead of $z$?

Comment: @Siddhant. Yes, sorry. Edited

Answer (score 30, accepted):

$$f:t\mapsto \frac {1}{\sqrt {1+t^2}} $$
is continuous at R, thus

$$F:x\mapsto \int_0^xf (t)dt $$ is differentiable at R and
$$F'(x)=f (x) $$

your function is
$$g (z)=F (z^3)-F (z^2) $$

it is differentiable at R and

$$g'(z)=3z^2f (z^3)-2zf (z^2) $$

$$=\frac {3z^2}{\sqrt {1+z^6}}-\frac {2z}{\sqrt {1+z^4}} $$

Comment: So $g'(z)=3z^2f (z^3)-2zf (z^2) =3z^2\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+z^6}}-2z\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+z^4}} $?

Answer (score 6):

Apply this: [Differentiation under the integral sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign).

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left( \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(x,t)\text{d}t \right ) = f(x,b(x))b'(x)-f(x,a(x))a'(x)+\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f_x(x,t)\text{d}t.$$

Answer (score 2):

differetiating with respect to $x$ gives
$$-2\,{\frac {x}{\sqrt {{x}^{4}+1}}}+3\,{\frac {{x}^{2}}{\sqrt {{x}^{6}+
1}}}
$$